# What are custom calling conventions?

Tags: c++, calling-convention

What are these? And how am I affected by these as a developer?

> **Related:**
>   [What are the different calling conventions in C/C++ and what do each mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949862/what-are-the-different-calling-conventions-in-c-c-and-what-do-each-mean)

Comment: In what context? Win32? Win64? Linux? Solaris? Intel? PowerPC?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949862/what-are-the-different-calling-conventions-in-c-c-and-what-do-each-mean

Comment: I suspect that people who voted to close this either (a) **don't understand what _custom_ calling conventions are** or (b) **didn't read the question correctly**. They're a special optimization, which is not covered by the duplicate question. Voting to reopen, and deleting the duplicate info.

Comment: I think they are highly irrelevant though.. because I very rarely see compilers optimizing by changing the calling convention.. This is because it can break a lot of stuff such as external linkage. In fact, I don't believe I've ever seen a compiler try to apply a custom convention, and it would only make sense for `static` functions, which usually just get inlined.

Comment: @Earlz: Whether or not it's a common technique is completely independent of whether or not this question should be closed. And it shouldn't have been. People were too hasty in assuming the duplicate question covered what was being asked.

Comment: @Earlz: Here's a compiler that took advantage of a custom calling convention to increase performance: http://donsbot.wordpress.com/2010/02/21/smoking-fast-haskell-code-using-ghcs-new-llvm-codegen/

Comment: @Laykes: Why? If you think the question deserves a downvote, how about telling the OP (and us) why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A *calling convention* describes how something may call another function. This requires parameters and state to be passed to the other function, so that it can execute and return control correctly. The way in which this is done has to be standardized and specified, so that the compiler knows how to order parameters for consumption by the remote function that's being called. There are several standard calling conventions, but the most common are **[`fastcall`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#fastcall)**, **[`stdcall`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#stdcall)**, and **[`cdecl`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl)**.

Usually, the term ***custom calling convention*** is a bit of a misnomer and refers to one of two things:

- A non-standard calling convention or one that isn't in widespread use (e.g. if you're building an architecture from scratch).
- A special optimization that a compiler/linker can perform that uses a one-shot calling convention for the purpose of improving performance.

In the latter case, this causes some values that would otherwise be pushed onto the stack to be stored in registers instead. The compiler will try to make this decision based on how the parameters are being used inside the code. For example, if the parameter is going to be used as a maximum value for a loop index, such that the index is compared against the max on each iteration to see if things should continue, that would be a good case for moving it into a register.

If the optimization is carried out, this typically reduces code size and improves performance.

> And how am I affected by these as a developer?

From your standpoint as a developer, you probably don't care; this is an optimization that will happen automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Each language, when calling a function, has a convention about what parameters will be passed in register variables vs on the stack, and how return values will be returned.

Sometimes a different convention than the standard one is used and that's referred to as a custom calling convention.

This is most common when interoperating between different languages.  For example, C and Pascal have different conventions about how to pass parameters.  From C's point of view, the Pascal calling convention could be referred to as a custom calling convention.

Comment: "pascal" isn't a custom calling convention - it's a normal, named calling convention. Also, it's history, isn't it? A relic from 16-bit days?

Comment: I said that it's a custom calling convention from C's point of view, which is correct.  Also, it's a suitable example to explain the concept, and certainly not deserving of a downvote.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you really need to care.

Normal calling conventions are things like __stdcall and __fastcall. They determine how your call signature is converted into a stack layout, who (caller or callee) is responsible for saving and restoring registers, etc. For example, __fastcall should use more registers where __stdcall would use more stack.

Custom calling conventions are optimised specifically for a particular function and the way it is used. They only happen, IIRC, for functions that are local to a particular module. That's how the compiler knows so much about how it's used, and also how you know that no external caller needs to be able to specify the convention.

Based on that, your compiler will use them automatically where appropriate, your code will run slightly faster and/or take slightly less space, but you don't really need to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are directly manipulating the stack or writing inline assembly referencing local variables, it does not affect you. Or if your interfacing with libraries linked with different calling conventions

What it is: Most compilers and such use a standard calling convention such as cdecl where function arguments are pushed in a certain order to the stack and such.

Comment: This isn't quite right. He asked about _custom_ calling conventions, which are a special optimization and don't correspond to any particular existing calling convention in particular.