# argument passing in x86-64 assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, x86-64, disassembly

I am learning x86-64 assembly and one thing that's confusing me is argument passing. from what i have understood till now that in case of normal function calls the arguments are pushed on stack  by the callie function and accessed by the called function through an offset from the base pointer And In case of a system call the argument is passed by using registers such as rdi , rsi etc. but when i try to look at the assemble code of following code snippet

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int by12(int);
int main(void)
{

    int x =  2;
    int y =  by12(x);
    printf("%d\n",y);
    return 0;
}


int by12(int a)
{
    return a*12;
}
```

then the assembly  result is

```
by12:
.LFB39:
    .cfi_startproc
    leal    (%rdi,%rdi,2), %edx
    leal    0(,%rdx,4), %eax
    ret

main:
.LFB38:
    .cfi_startproc
    subq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movl    $2, %edi
    call    by12
    movl    %eax, %edx
    movl    $.LC0, %esi
    movl    $1, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    __printf_chk
    movl    $0, %eax
    addq    $8, %rsp
```

i am not able to understand why the generated assembly code uses rdi register instead of using an stack base offset ?
edit- i saw the stack based method in this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395743/how-does-argument-passing-work)

Comment: Because optimization? How do you build to generate the assembly code?

Comment: Usually the compiler will follow the ABI defined by your target platform, at least for public functions. So your notion that arguments are pushed to stack looks to be invalid. Check your target platform ABI definition.

Comment: I used the -Og flag while compiling with gcc

Comment: The `-Og` flag can still do some optimization, try `-O0` to disable all optimizations instead.

Comment: I tried using the -O0 flag but the only difference is the way the result is calculated. no difference in argument passing.