# cmake making all symbols in static lib external

Tags: c, cmake

I've got a `CMakeList.txt` which builds a static lib:

```
project(SharedComponents C)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
include_directories(../include)
add_library(SharedComponents STATIC ATMIDIUtils.c ../include/ATMIDIUtils.h)
```

ATMIDIUtils.c

```
void splitMIDIValue(MIDILongValue value, MIDIValue * _Nonnull separated) 
{
    separated->MSB = (value >> 7) & ATMIDIMaxValue;
    separated->LSB = value & ATMIDIMaxValue;
}
```

ATMIDIUtils.h

```
void splitMIDIValue(MIDILongValue value, MIDIValue * _Nonnull separated);
```

This compiles ok. I'm then attempting to build a unit test and link with it, and it says the symbol is missing:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"splitMIDIValue(unsigned short, MIDIValue*)", referenced from:
  ATMIDIUtilsTests_test_split_midi_value_Test::TestBody() in ATMIDIUtilsTests.cxx.o
```

nm shows the symbol is external:

```
0000000000000330 (__TEXT,__text) external _splitMIDIValue
```

Why are all the symbols missing from my library? `ATMIDIUtils.c` contains the function implementation but it seems it is not getting compiled into the static lib.

Answer (score 3):

> Why are all the symbols missing from my library? ATMIDIUtils.c contains the function implementation but it seems it is not getting compiled into the static lib.

They are there and `nm(1)` is telling you as much. The linker just doesn't find the symbol because you compiled the library with a C compiler, but the unit test is in C++.

You are missing an `extern "C"` in front of the function prototype. usually the header as a whole is put into an `extern "C"` block conditional on `__cplusplus` being defined, like so:

```
#ifndef ATMIDI_UTILS_H_
#define ATMIDI_UTILS_H_

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void splitMIDIValue(MIDILongValue value, MIDIValue * _Nonnull separated);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* ATMIDI_UTILS_H_ */
```

Check this answer for why this is necessary: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11257433/1257035

Comment: Thanks so much that was really confusing me! What would `nm` look like if the symbols weren't present? I thought external meant they weren't present in the lib.

Comment: @Nick external means they have external linkage (i.e. exported). Not present symbols are undefined.