# Is the C++ calling convention constrained by the standard, since the return type of a function does not need to be defined when the fn is declared?

Tags: c++, return-value, return-type

While studying the [One Definition Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) in Wikipedia, I became stuck on the following example in the [Examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule#Examples) section:

```
struct S;     // declaration of S
...
S f();        // ok, no definition required
...
```

I know that space on the stack needs to be allotted for the return value, but seeing this example made me think that C++ calling conventions might dictate that stack management for the return value is handled by the code block in which the function is defined, rather than the code block in which it is called.  So I investigated "C vs. C++ calling convention" (recalling that the issue of stack return value allocation might be a primary difference), and came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/949873/368896), which indicates that "calling convention" is not defined by the standard.

However, given the apparent requirement that the above code snippet is valid, it seems to me that there **must** be some constraints on calling convention in order to support the above code snippet.

Am I right?  Does the C++ standard implicitly require that stack management for the return value of a function be handled by the code that defines the function, in order to support the syntax above?

Comment: As you have written your example, Both Struct S and function f are forward declarations.  The Compiler Will indeed complain if you attempt to use either

Comment: Ahh - how obvious.  I will update the comment in the Wikipedia article.  You might as well post your comment as an answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, I believe that default calling convention ( and optional calling conventions ) are explicitly implementation dependent with the exception of those with external linkage.  If you search the c++ standard for "calling convention".  It is mentioned only once in section 7.5 Linkage Specifications

Comment: Note that it's not legal to actually define `f` *or* call `f` while `S` is still incomplete.

Comment: @Dan Nissenbaum; I've been hooked on your question history for the last hour.  I'm Truly impressed.  I've learned a ton.  +1 recommend to everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments

> As you have written your example, Both Struct S and function f are forward declarations. The Compiler Will indeed complain if you attempt to use either

** EDIT as noted by Steven Sudit, function f is not a forward declaration but a function prototype**

and

> Also, I believe that default calling convention ( and optional calling conventions ) are explicitly implementation dependent with the exception of those with external linkage. If you search the c++ standard for "calling convention". It is mentioned only once in section 7.5 Linkage Specifications

As to your specific question

> Am I right? Does the C++ standard implicitly require that stack management for the return value of a function be handled by the code that defines the function, in order to support the syntax above?

Definitely not, as many compilers support calling conventions where the values are not even passed/returned on the stack (FASTCALL) or microsofts version of (thiscall) where the caller cleans the stack.

Comment: Small nit about your original comment: there are no "forward" declarations of functions, just declarations. The one with the function body is called the definition, instead. http://www.cprogramming.com/declare_vs_define.html

Answer (score 3):

The C/C++ standard does not define [calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions).  That is the job of compiler vendors to implement on their own, as evident by the fact that calling convention keywords start with underscores indicating they are vendor-provided extensions.

The C/C++ standard defines the base rules (how to assign values to parameters and return values, pass by-value vs by-reference, etc), but the calling conventions dictate how to accomplish those rules in different ways (passing parameters via stack or registers, in which order, which registers, who cleans up the stack, etc).

In the casev of x86, vendors have agreed on the semantics of the `__cdecl` and `__stdcall` calling conventions for interoperability (although there are some slight variations in `__cdecl` implementations in some cases), but other calling conventions are vendor-specific (Microsoft's `__fastcall`/`__thiscall`, Borland's `__fastcall`/`__safecall`/`__msfastcall`, etc).

In the case of x64, there is only one calling convention, dictated by x64 itself. Calling convention keywords are silently ignored by x64 compiler so existing code will still compile and work correctly (as long as it is not using inline assembly to access/manipulate the call stack directly).