# Getting "Symbol Lookup Error" when calling C library from C++ (Node.js Addon)

Tags: javascript, c++, c, node.js, coffeescript

I am working on a Node.js addon that needs to wrap the objects from a [C library](https://github.com/Yona-Appletree/LEDscape) in C++ so they can be accessed from client-side JavaScript (written in CoffeeScript).

The C++ module compiles, but when I try to run it through Node.js JavaScript, the C library fails to be called with a `symbol lookup error` that I'm having problems debugging.

The error is below:
`node: symbol lookup error: /var/lib/cloud9/ledscape-wrapper/wrapper/build/Release/wrapper.node: undefined symbol: ledscape_init`

`wrapper.node` is the compiled package, `ledscape_init` is the function in the library I am trying to call.

I've tried to trace the code and find the relevant snippets across multiple files.  I've dropped lines I've deemed extraneous.

```coffeescript
# "AllFade.coffee"
@ledscape = require "./ledscape.js"
@frames[1] = @ledscape.LedscapeInit()
# "Ledscape.coffee"
wrapper = require "./build/Release/wrapper"
module.exports = wrapper
```

wrapper.cc

```
extern "C" {
#include <ledscape.h>
}
#include <node.h>
#include <v8.h>
#include <node_object_wrap.h>
#include "LedscapeWrapper.h"

Handle<Value> LedscapeInit(const Arguments& args) {
    HandleScope scope;
    return scope.Close(LedscapeWrapper::NewInstance(args));
}

void InitAll(Handle<Object> exports, Handle<Object> module) {
    LedscapeWrapper::Init(module);
    NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "LedscapeInit", LedscapeInit);
}

NODE_MODULE(wrapper, InitAll)
```

LedscapeWrapper.h

```
extern "C" {
#include <ledscape.h>
}
#include <node.h>
#include <node_object_wrap.h>
using namespace v8;

class LedscapeWrapper : public node::ObjectWrap {
    public:
        static void Init(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports);
        static Handle<Value> NewInstance(const Arguments& args);
        inline ledscape_t* value() const { return value_; }
    private:
        explicit LedscapeWrapper(ledscape_t* value = ledscape_init(1));
        ~LedscapeWrapper();
        static Handle<Value> New(const Arguments& args);
        static v8::Persistent<v8::Function> constructor;
        ledscape_t* value_;
};
```

LedscapeWrapper.cpp

```
extern "C" {
#include <ledscape.h>
}
#include <node.h>
#include "LedscapeWrapper.h"
using namespace v8;

void LedscapeWrapper::Init(Handle<Object> exports) {
    Local<FunctionTemplate> tpl = FunctionTemplate::New(New);
    tpl->SetClassName(String::NewSymbol("LedscapeWrapper"));
    tpl->InstanceTemplate()->SetInternalFieldCount(1);
    constructor = Persistent<Function>::New(tpl->GetFunction());
    exports->Set(String::NewSymbol("LedscapeWrapper"), constructor);
}

Handle<Value> LedscapeWrapper::New(const Arguments& args) {
    HandleScope scope;
    if(args.IsConstructCall()) {
        ledscape_t* ledscape = ledscape_init(args[0]->NumberValue());
        LedscapeWrapper* obj = new LedscapeWrapper(ledscape);
        obj->Wrap(args.This());
        return args.This();
    }
    else {
        const int argc = 1;
        Local<Value> argv[argc] = { args[0] };
        return scope.Close(constructor->NewInstance(argc, argv));
    }
}

Handle<Value> LedscapeWrapper::NewInstance(const Arguments& args) {
    HandleScope scope;
    const int argc = 1;
    Handle<Value> argv[argc] = { args[0] };
    Local<Object> instance = constructor->NewInstance(argc, argv);
    return scope.Close(instance);
}
```

binding.gyp

```
{
  "targets": [{
    "target_name": "wrapper",
    "sources": ["wrapper.cc","LedscapeWrapper.cpp","LedscapeFrameWrapper.cpp"],
    'include_dirs': ['/opt/ledscape/'],
    'link_settings': {  'library_dirs': ['/opt/ledscape']  },
  }],
}
```

I think the problem is in one of the calls to `ledscape_init()` inside LedscapeWrapper.cpp, and that it is unable to find the library ([ledscape.h](https://github.com/Yona-Appletree/LEDscape/blob/master/ledscape.h)), but I'm not primarily a C/C++ developer.

I tried to look into the `nm` tool, either from GNU or Node, but it refused to examine the `.node` file, and I wasn't finding any usage pointers online.

Comment: Did you try linking directly with the static/dynamic library with `"libraries": [ "/opt/ledscape/ledscape.a" ]` (or `ledscape.so`) instead of using `link_settings`?

Comment: @mscdex There aren't any files with `.a` or `.so` extensions.  Are either of those automatically generated?  (Sorry, I don't have much experience with C/C++)

Comment: Did you compile ledscape first? Otherwise you might need to make a gyp file for ledscape and then have your binding.gyp point to that as a dependency. Without manually compilation or the setting up of a dependency gyp file, ledscape isn't being linked in to your app (either statically or dynamically), hence the missing symbols.

Comment: @mscdex Sorry for the delay.  `"libraries": ["/opt/LED/LEDScape/ledscape.o"]` fixes the first issue, but then I got `undefined symbol: pru_init`, which `/opt/LED/LEDScape/ledscape.h` includes in `pru.h`.  `"libraries": ["/opt/LED/LEDScape/ledscape.o", "/opt/LED/LEDScape/pru.o"]` fixes that, but results in `undefined symbol: prussdrv_init`.  Is there a better way to fix these than including more dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens because, the actual programme cannot find the dynamic library(.so file) What i am suggest is make a dynamic library and add it to the ,current lookup path such that /usr/lib in linux

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was encapsolating the included C header file with:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
```

...

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Arranged like this (from https://github.com/bartobri/base64-simple):

```
// Copyright (c) 2017 Brian Barto
//
// This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
// under the terms of the MIT License. See LICENSE for more details.

#ifndef BASE64SIMPLE_H
#define BASE64SIMPLE_H 1

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

#include <stdlib.h>
/*
 * Function Prototypes
 */
char *base64simple_encode(unsigned char *, size_t);
unsigned char *base64simple_decode(char *, size_t, size_t *);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/949889