# node: symbol lookup error: , undefined symbol: _ZN4demo3sumEii

Tags: c++, node.js

I am creating a C++ addon and I wanted to use a static library. i have a .a library libarith which does simple addition.

```
-libarith.a
-hello.cc
-hello.js
```

my binding.gyp file is as follows:-

```
{ "targets": [
        {
        "target_name": "addon",
        "sources": [ "hello.cc" ],
        "libraries": [ "-/home/folder/api/addon/libarith.a" ],
        "cflags!": [ "-fno-exceptions" ],
        "cflags": [ "-std=c++11" ],
        "cflags_cc!": [ "-fno-exceptions" ]
        }
        ]
    }
```

When i compile my hello.cc it compiles well. But when i run my addon , it gives following error:

node: symbol lookup error: `/home/folder/api/addon/build/Release/addon.node: undefined symbol: _ZN4demo3sumEii.`

I am new to addons, a help would be very much appreciated.

Code Snippet:-
libarith.a contains:

```
int sum(int a ,int b){

    return a+b;
}
```

// hello.cc

```
#include <node.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <v8.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace v8;
namespace demo {

using v8::FunctionCallbackInfo;
using v8::Isolate;
using v8::Local;
using v8::Object;
using v8::String;
using v8::Value;
void newmethod(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args)
{ extern int sum(int,int);

Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
double abc= sum(4,5);
Local<Number> newnumber =Number::New(isolate,abc);
v8::String::Utf8Value r(args[1]);
    std::string rst(*r);
Local<String> first = String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "firstargument");
Local<String> second = String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "secondargument");
Local<Object> newobj= Object::New(isolate);
newobj->Set(first,String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, *s));
newobj->Set(second,newnumber);
args.GetReturnValue().Set(newobj);

}
void init(Local<Object> exports) {
  NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "newmethod", newmethod);
}
NODE_MODULE(addon, init)
}
```

//hello.js

```
const addon = require('./build/Release/addon');

var ss = "helloo";
var samplestring = "It is not a sample string";
console.log(addon.newmethod(samplestring, ss));
```

EDIT:- The solution worked as follows. I tried to create a separate directory for the libraries and it worked fine.

Comment: libarith.a contains: 
int sum(int a ,int b){
 
 return a+b;
} 

// hello.cc
#include <node.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <v8.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace v8;
namespace demo {

using v8::FunctionCallbackInfo;
using v8::Isolate;
using v8::Local;
using v8::Object;
using v8::String;
using v8::Value;





void newmethod(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args)
{ extern int sum(int,int);

Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
double abc= sum(4,5);
Local<Number> newnumber =Number::New(isolate,abc);

Comment: I have attached the code snippet. Hope it will be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says, it cannot find the declaration(implementation of `.h`). I think you give wrong direction to your library. There are two solutions:

1. Write full directory to your library at `binding.gyp` `~/whereItIsLocated`, in my case it was `~/CLionProjects/node-player-core/PlayerCore/lib/x64/yourLibraryName.a`
2. If previous solution couldn't help, you can copy you library to `/usr/lib`. You can do it with `sudo cp ~/whereLibraryLocated /usr/lib`.

Comment: I tried both but not working, I created library using command:
ar cr libarith.a sum.o .

Comment: I tried both but  it's not working. I created the library using :
ar cr libarith.a sum.o 
Is there something i did wrong?

Comment: Can you please create shared library (.so) and try these methods? Because, I had similar problem.

Comment: I think, you didn't create declaration for function `sum()`

Comment: Above is my code, can you please tell me where to specify the declaration? I have declared in hello.cc as  : extern int sum(int,int);

Comment: @AmitNagar Can you try to use `newmethod` without `sum` method? Will it give error or not?

Comment: Yes ,without sum it is working fine. Even with sum it is compiling properly but when I try to run addon it gives me unknown symbol error.

Comment: Let's try to create `hello.h` and put `int sum(int, int);` there. Then include it to `hello.cc`. Let's see the result. Or another problem can be with linking of library.

Comment: @Jasuberek, Thanks for your help. It worked when i created the header and put my libraries in a separate directory.

Answer (score 2):

Specify the .so library used for appropriate .h file in the binding.gyp file helps me to solve same issue:

```
"libraries": [
  "/usr/lib/mylib.so"
]
```

This links help me to found it: [Getting "Symbol Lookup Error" when calling C library from C++ (Node.js Addon)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476513/getting-symbol-lookup-error-when-calling-c-library-from-c-node-js-addon)

Comment: This one worked for me. I was trying to link libpulse to my addon, but adding `'-lpulse'` to `'cflags'` or `'cflags_cc'` in binding.gyp was not working, still resulting in a symbol lookup error. what ended up working was `'libraries': [ '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse.so' ]`. I found the .so file by luck with the command `find . -name "libpulse.so"`. There should be more documentation on this process.