# How to convert Java double[][] to C++ <vector<vector>> JNI?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have a 2D Java double array:

```
 double[][] jdestination_list = new double[][];
```

How do I convert this to:

```
vector<vector<double>>  destinationListCpp;
```

---

My JNI call is as follows:

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_JNI_Call(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jobjectArray jdestination_list,)

    // always on the lookout for null pointers. Everything we get from Java
    // can be null.
    jsize OuterDim = jdestination_list ? env->GetArrayLength(jdestination_list) : 0;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > destinationListCpp(OuterDim);

for(jsize i = 0; i < OuterDim; ++i) {
    jdoubleArray inner = static_cast<jdoubleArray>(env->GetObjectArrayElement(jdestination_list, i));

    // again: null pointer check
    if(inner) {
        // Get the inner array length here. It needn't be the same for all
        // inner arrays.
        jsize InnerDim = env->GetArrayLength(inner);
        destinationListCpp[i].resize(InnerDim);

        jdouble *data = env->GetDoubleArrayElements(inner, 0);
        std::copy(data, data + InnerDim, destinationListCpp[i].begin());
        env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(inner, data, 0);
    }
}
```

I keep getting:

> undefined reference to void Clas::Java_JNI_Call

Any suggestions on how this can be done?

Comment: Did you declare Java_JNI_Call inside your `Class` for some reason? It has to be a top-level function for JNI to work (or you have to go the `registerNatives` route)

Comment: Also, why are you casting each element to `jintArray` if you have a `double[][]`?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. TI think that is a mistake. It should be  `doubleArray inner = static_cast<jdoubleArray>`. Will update code accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code generates a **C**-type function called `Java_JNI_Call`:

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_JNI_Call(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jobjectArray jdestination_list,)
```

That **C**-type function ([note the `extern "C"`...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c-in-c)) is not a member of any class, it can not be overloaded, and the function name does not undergo [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) as a C++ function does.

This error message is complaining you haven't provided a  definition of the **C++** function `Clas::Java_JNI_Call`:

```
undefined reference to void Clas::Java_JNI_Call
```

Because you haven't.

JNI calls are technically **C** functions, not C++ functions.  You can get away with using C++ functions via JNI's `registerNatives()` function on [systems where C and C++ calling conventions are compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949862/what-are-the-different-calling-conventions-in-c-c-and-what-do-each-mean), but you have to use top-level or static class methods as the JNI call has no associated C++ object that could be used as a C++ `this`.