# Memory Address of Return Value (Assembly Language C++)

Tags: c++

I've been given some C++ code which is a method called clamp that returns a integer value. I've been asked to look at the stack in memory which i have and through disassembly i am suppose to be able to see the return values address in the stack. [My disassembly and code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvnvh.png)

What am i meant to look for as i cant find any information online?

```
int& clamp(int& value, int low, int high) {
    if (value < low)
        return low;
    if (value > high)
        return high;
    return value;
}
```

I've attached a picture of what i can see and what i believe to be the return values memory address which is red in the memory window. Above is the code for the method as well.

Comment: This returns an integer reference, not a value. Optimizer can change things and return value may just be in a register. Not necessarily on the stack.

Comment: Have you discussed `calling conventions` in your class? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949862/what-are-the-different-calling-conventions-in-c-c-and-what-do-each-mean

Comment: I believe you highlighted the part of the stack used to pass the parameters. That's the address of A in red. That same value should appear in EAX as the returned address.

Comment: The function itself results in Undefined Behavior because it potentially returns a reference to a local variable (parameter).