# Returning an array from c++ function into c# script in unity

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine

I have a c++ function defined as

```cpp
extern "C" Point* myFunc(int size) {
  Point *p = new Point[size];
  return p;
}
```

where point is just a struct defined as

```cpp
extern "C" typedef struct _point {
  int x;
  int y;
} Point;
```

and inside my c# code I have

```cs
[DllImport("MyLibrary")]
static extern Point[] myFunc(int size);
```

and I use it as

```cs
Point[] newPoints = myFunc(3);
Debug.Log(newPoints.Length);
```

But the output is

```
33
```

The function is just an example, but the lenght of the array returned shouldn't be known before the function call.
What is the correct way of returning an array to c# in order to use it, know its size and access it without incurring in any IndexOutOfRangeException?

Comment: Try declaring the array as `Point p [size] = { };`.  You can also try adding the calling convention, eg. `[DllImport("MyLibrary", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]`.  [Here is a link for Calling Conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949862/what-are-the-different-calling-conventions-in-c-c-and-what-do-each-mean)

Comment: @hijinxbassist what if I don't know the size a priori?

Comment: Size is the param you had in your myFunc function.  Not sure how you'd declare the array without size, except for initializing it with items.

Comment: If you don't know the size, how do you expect the marshaller to figure it out?  Look at @Sunius's answer, you need to tell the marshaller how to marshal the array

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to determine array length from a pointer. It seems instead of throwing an exception, Unity guesses and guesses wrong. The correct way to return data in an array from C++ is to pass an array of correct size in from C#:

```
extern "C" void GetPoints(Point* points, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        points[i].x = points[i].y = i;
}
```

And then on C# side:

```
[DllImport("MyLibrary", EntryPoint = "GetPoints")]
static extern void GetPointsNative([In][Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] Point[] points, int size);

static Point[] GetPoints(int size)
{
    var points = new Point[size];
    GetPointsNative(points, size);
    return points;
}
```